# Find permutation matrix $X \in \{0,1\}^{N \times N}$ in order to make $XAX \geq_c B$

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, permutations, linear-programming, combinatorial-geometry

I need to solve a problem to find out the best permutation matrix $X \in \{0,1\}^{N \times N}$ which would maximize the number of elements in matrix $XAX$ which are above (component-wise) matrix $B$

i.e.
\begin{align}
&\max_X sum (XAX \geq_c B)  \\
&X \in \{0,1\}^{N \times N}\hspace{0.1cm} \text{ is a permutation matrix} \\
&A \in R^{N \times N}\hspace{0.9cm} \text{ is a symmetric Z-matrix} \\
&B \in R^{N \times N}\hspace{0.9cm} \text{ is a symmetric matrix} 
\end{align}

Can anyone help me in this please?

Comment: What is a Z-matrix? Is it the thing associated to chemical  bonds? Or do you mean that the entries are all integers? Do you know any relations between $A$ and $B$, like that $AB = BA$, for instance?

Comment: @JohnHughes  $A$ is a Z-matrix in mathematical sense, which means all non-diagonal entries are negative. Both $A$ & $B$ are symmetric, hence $AB = BA$ holds.